# Keep existing state for all items when changing workflow

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I implemented a custom workflow and set it for Document (Page):

- added in my default profile
- upgrade step import workflow
- in `portal_workflow/manage_selectWorkflows` set it for Document (Page), click on `Change`, click on `Update security settings`

It was set and it is working. The problem is my all pages are now in `Private` state even if the most of them were in `Published` state before.

I did it in my local application, so it is not a real problem. But how can I set it (in production website) to avoid this issue?

I think maybe it is related to `initial_state` value:

```
<dc-workflow workflow_id="foo_publication_workflow" title="Foo Publication Workflow" description="" state_variable="review_state" initial_state="private" manager_bypass="False">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to migrate your existing content with old workflow to the new one.

In the ZMI portal_workflow for the Document type must be specified the OLD workflow.

Then go to the Plone control panel -> Types (@@types-controlpanel) -> choose Document in the drop down menu and then choose the new workflow.

Now you are able to properly configure exact match between old states and the new ones.

Click `apply` to start migration.

hth,
alessandro.